# How do I set two dynamic header rows in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How do I set two dynamic header rows in jquery datatable ??

```
    function updateTable(params) {
    $.getJSON(
    window.location.pathname,
    params,
    function(result) {
        // Set table title
        $('#title_box').text(result.title);

        // Set table headers
        var column_titles = result.column_titles1.map(function(header) {
            return {
                'title': header
            };
        });

        // Let datatables render the rest.
        $('#datatable').dataTable({
            "ordering": false,
            "searching": false,
            "paging": false,
            "info": false,
            "columns": column_titles,
            "data": table.data
        });
    }
);}}
```

with this I was able to set only one dynamic header. I need to set two header rows from the data that I return from ajax response. I've separated the the two columns as:

```
    {"column_titles1":[["value1"],["value2"]], "columns_titles2": [["value1"],["value2"]]}
```

Comment: Isn't this what you need? https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: No I need to set the table headers from my data. There are no problems getting the data for my table.

Comment: It's not clear to me, how you want to have table with two header rows? What is the usage for that?

Comment: I need to have two headers like this - https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Comment: But I need to create this headers dynamically.

Comment: I think you need to do this directly with jQuery. The `columns` configuration key is for describing the data columns.

Comment: `{"column_titles1":[["value1"],["value2"]], "columns_titles2": [["value1"],["value2"]]}` is not useful for settings columns. At leasat it must be a object literal holding titles. Please provide a real example.  As Santoro mentions, you will need to add the second row of headers programmatically (after the table is initialised) since dataTables columns only support one row of headers. The inserted second row of headers should then be inserted as the first row.

Comment: Yeah, I agree I was able to add the second header row as the first row of the table. But can we make that particular row fixed at the top, which may give it a header like a look.

Comment: As there are fixed columns, can we have fixed rows.

Answer (score 2):

Do this directly with jQuery. Making some assumptions here because I can't see your HTML, but assuming you have a `thead` on your table, find it with a jQuery selector and set the HTML to:

```
var header_rows = ["column_titles1", "column_titles2"].map(function(z) {
    return '<tr>' + result[z].map(function(y) {
            return '<td>' + y + '</td>';
        }).join("") + '</tr>'
}).join("");

$("#myTable thead").html(header_rows);
```

Comment: How will column_titles1 and column_titles2 get its json value.

Comment: I provided the best example answer I could based on the example you provided. Part of coding is figuring out how to apply examples to your specific use case. I have faith in you!